# how to update information_schema.tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, information-schema, mysqladmin

i have a table A and i want to update the creation time of this table.
I understand i cant simple update ( using update query) as it is not any table.

Is there any way i can update it.

for example creation time is '2015-07-03 12:03:33' to '2015-06-03 12:03:33'

Comment: What is the storage engine of table A ? MyISAM or InnoDB ?

Comment: Storage engine of table A is Innodb

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change the creation time of an InnoDB table.

Answer (score 2):

Information_Schema are views and read-only. Yo can not update meta data about tables, only by modifying actual table with `ALTER TABLE`. If you do an `ALTER TABLE` you will have current timestamp in meta data.

> INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a database within each MySQL instance, the place
>   that stores information about all the other databases that the MySQL
>   server maintains. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA database contains several
>   read-only tables. They are actually views, not base tables, so there
>   are no files associated with them, and you cannot set triggers on
>   them. Also, there is no database directory with that name.
>
> Although you can select INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the default database
>   with a USE statement, you can only read the contents of tables, not
>   perform INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations on them.

[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  /  INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html)

What's the exact reason you need to change meta data?

Comment: This wasn't enough for me. I also had to run OPTIMIZE TABLE